# Pod install does not work with my react-native app

Tags: react-native, expo, cocoapods

I'm trying to build an app on ios in react native using eas build.

Things goes well except wen it comes to do pod install in the IOS directory.
I got this error :

```
⚠️ react-native-unimodules is deprecated in favor of expo
⚠️ Follow this guide to migrate: https://expo.fyi/expo-modules-migration
Using Expo modules
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
[stderr] 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String: "relative URI: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec" (FrozenError)
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/pod:23:in `load'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
[stderr] 
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/generic.rb:1491:in `find_proxy': relative URI: /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec (URI::BadURIError)
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open-uri.rb:218:in `block in open_loop'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open-uri.rb:235:in `block in open_loop'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open-uri.rb:233:in `catch'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open-uri.rb:233:in `open_loop'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.7/2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open-uri.rb:174:in `open_uri'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/podspec_source.rb:19:in `block in fetch'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/podspec_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:993:in `fetch_external_source'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:972:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:971:in `each'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:971:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:970:in `fetch_external_sources'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:117:in `analyze'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/pod:23:in `load'
[stderr] 
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
pod exited with non-zero code: 1
```

And this is my Podfile :
[image]

I'm on expo 44. And my pod version is 1.12.1 on Mac M1. Cacaopods 1.12.1 and ruby 2.6.10

Any ideas ?

Thanks

I've found nothing on google with this type of error for mobile app. So I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I was using an old version of Ruby, so I downloaded a newer version; I was using Ruby 2.6.10, whereas passing it to 3.0.0 solved it.

And for the bad URI on Folly, I changed it with this line:

```
pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec'
```

I don't know why—maybe when I've upgrade the project from Expo 39 to Expo 44?—the `Folly.podspec` disappeared and was replaced with `RTC-Folly.podspec`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on M1?
If you are you can try running:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

If you are not, probably pods are already installed so you can try with `pod update` or removing `ios/build` and `ios/Pods`, then `pod install` again.

Comment: Yes I'm on M1, I've tried what you give me, I still go the same error but ffi has been installed. I'm still trying to find